# Export CSV after a ForEach loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I tried to export these Active Directory users (after creating them) into a CSV, but I think I'm going about it the wrong way. Could I get some help with this? I need to export the samAccountName and SID to the CSV file but can't seem to get anything exported

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GroupProject3Usernames2.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $userPrincipal = $_."UserName" + "mycorp.com"
New-ADUser $userPrincipal `
 -SamAccountName  $_."UserName" `
 -givenname $_."FirstName" `
 -surname $_."LastName" `
 -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force) `
 -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true  `
 -Enabled $true
Add-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" $_."UserName";
Write-Host $_."UserName" " Created"
} | out-file "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output.csv" -SamAccountName -SID
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not really piping anything to the file. Remove the pipe to out file and replace your write host to:
   "$($_.UserName) Created" | out-file "your file" -append

Comment: How would I get the SID in there too in a different column? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Store the result of New-ADuser into a variable called $newUser. Then include "$($newUser.SID)" in your write host.